# Why is there a huge white gap in the middle of product page?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, layout, themes

I don't think I've changed anything but two issues have occurred.

1) When product zoom is enabled it causes a huge blank space in the middle of the page.

2) Related Products are no longer displayed in a horizontal row, instead they display vertically in one column.

Page can be viewed [here](https://www.tomcoke.com/product/2-38ctw-blue-sapphire-0-98ctw-diamond-18ct-white-gold-bracelet/)

Comment: What is the code you are asking about?  You can edit your question to add your code and more information.

Comment: I see a (seemingly) random div with padding: 100% in there... I viewed in chrome and used 'inspect element'.  Could not figure out how to zoom though.

Comment: try to check the css (style.css?ver=2.4 - line no. 8107) and remove the height:auto, if it works let us proceed further